# What does aop.xml File in Spring-Aspects Artifact?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I activated aspectj load time weaving for my application and added an aop.xml file defining my aspects.

I found out that the spring-aspects jar on my classpath does contain an aop.xml file too and is loaded when I configure my application to start with the aspectjweaver.jar as java agent.

It seems, that this file is unused, when no weaving is activated but does increase the application startup time when activated. What is this file used for?

Comment: I correclty answered your original question long ago, but the question is still listed as unaccepted, because you did not accept the answer.

Comment: Hi. I must agree that my question is not written well. This makes it hard to define what to accept as an answer. You definitely helped to get a better understanding of how this mechanism works with Spring. I really appreciate your help. I asked what this file is used for. Now I know: "The aop.xml file is not unused as I initially thought. Spring-aspects is automatically using load time weaving and its packaged aop.xml file e.g. for enabling the @CreatedDate annotation. Regardless of the definition of a javaagent as JVM parameter." Given this context, should I still accept your anwer?

Comment: My answer is correct independent of your context. You asked about the file's purpose, and I explained it in more detail than your fuzzy question actually deserves. I see no reason why you should not accept it. BTW, I have no idea what you are talking about with `@CreatedDate`.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about [this file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-aspects/src/main/resources/META-INF/aop.xml). Quoting its content, slightly reformatted:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- AspectJ load-time weaving config file to install common Spring aspects. -->
<aspectj>
  <!--<weaver options="-showWeaveInfo"/>-->
  <aspects>
    <aspect name="org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect"/>
    <aspect name="org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AnnotationAsyncExecutionAspect"/>
    <aspect name="org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect"/>
    <aspect name="org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.JtaAnnotationTransactionAspect"/>
    <aspect name="org.springframework.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect"/>
    <aspect name="org.springframework.cache.aspectj.JCacheCacheAspect"/>
  </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Firstly, talking about `spring-aspects`, you need to understand that it uses native AspectJ, not proxy-based Spring AOP. The technique used to weave aspects is called load-time weaving (LTW), i.e. target class byte code gets transformed during class-loading by a weaving agent that usually is added to the JVM command line like this:

```
java ... -javaagent:/my/aspectjweaver.jar -javaagent:/my/spring-aspects.jar
```

You see, you can use a single or even multiple agents at the same time. This is a generic, standardised JVM mechanism. AspectJ simply happens to use it, like many other Java agents do.

There is a chapter in the Spring manual, describing [how to use native AspectJ in Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/using-aspectj.html). One brief paragraph deals with [`aop.xml`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/using-aspectj.html#aop-aj-ltw-aop_dot_xml), pointing further to the corresponding [AspectJ manual chapter](https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw-configuration.html).

In a nutshell:

- AspectJ LTW is configurable. The way you configure it is an `aop.xml` file.
- `spring-aspects` therefore comes with its own `aop.xml` file. It lists the currently six (6) aspects contained within the library.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thorough answer! I have spring-aspects in my classpath for some time now because it is a dependency for the spring auditing feature in my Hibernate entities (@CreatedDate, ... ). But I did not have a Java agent defined for the application startup so far. How are the 6 Spring aspects activated then?

Comment: Please study [this Spring manual chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/using-aspectj.html#aop-aj-ltw-spring). Probably, it is configured correctly for your container. I am not a Spring user at all, but when running plain Spring or Spring Boot applications from the command line to answer questions here, I always needed `-javaagent:` arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Spring can activate LTW without using the -javaagent: argument. Using @EnableLoadTimeWaving already enables weaving the aspects defined in my own aop.xml.

Comment: If I use @EnableLoadTimeWeaving OR a -javaagent: for activating LTW for my aspects, the Spring defined aspects get woven too. This seems like an unwanted side effect to me. Therefore my initial question, what these Spring aspects are for. should  I edit my original question or should I delete it and write a new one?

Comment: I know Spring can use LTW without `-javaagent` in some containers. But when just rinning a simple Spring or Spring Boot program from the command line, you need a Java agent according to my experience. If yours is different,I would be interested to know how you pulled that off.

Comment: Why is it an unwanted side effect that you put `spring-aspects` on the classpath and are surprised that it is used when you activate LTW? It is the natural thing to happen, but you can override the _aop.xml_ from that JAR in your application, if you do not need some or even all the aspects from there.

Comment: As I understand, `spring-aspects` is already using load time weaving e.g. for enabling the `@CreatedDate` annotation. These are not Spring managed and require the "full" aspectj functionality. By adding the `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` to the configuration, Spring is looking for other aop.xml files in the classpath and does the weaving for the custom defined aspects too. The used loadtimeweaver is selected automatically depending on the application container. `TomcatLoadTimeWeaver` in my case. There is also the option to define another weaver to be used.

Comment: I guess, by adding the weaving javaagent as JVM parameter, the weaving happened twice which was not a desired behavior.

Comment: Just like I said, for you it works, because the container (Tomcat) plays nice with Spring. Just running a Spring application from the IDE needs the agent on the command line. As for "weaving twice", not, I do not think so.